# javafx listen KeyEvent global

Tags: javafx

Does anyone know how to globally listen to all keyboard events in a javafx application?
No matter which Node is focused or shown.

In Swing it was achieved by this:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventPostProcessor(new KeyEventPostProcessor() {
        public boolean postProcessKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            //System.out.println("postProcessKeyEvent "+ e.getComponent().getName());
            // If the key should not be dispatched to the
            // focused component, set discardEvent to true
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Thanks,
Hugo

Comment: I am guessing you need to register the key event on the root node.

Comment: You can use `yourWindow.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.ANY, yourHandler)` but note you will only receive the events if they're not consumed somewhere in the scene graph. If you want to see all events use `addEventFilter`. Make sure not to consume the event yourself when using a filter here; otherwise, the events will never reach the focused node.

Comment: Tried the setting event on root node but the event does not work when another node has focus.